# Using Spread Operator in Redux mapDispatchToProps and SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, sweetalert2

When I include the `swal` action creators in `mapDispatchToProps` as such

```
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            getAnimal: (_id) => dispatch(getAnimal(_id)),
            ...swal
        }
    }
```

`this.props.getAnimal()` works correctly dispatching an action when called, but `this.props.showAlert()` which is provided by `...swal` does not dispatch the action when called!

However, if we were to replace the `...swal` spread operator to result in:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getAnimal: (_id) => dispatch(getAnimal(_id)),
        showAlert: () => dispatch(swal.showAlert()),
        hideAlert: () => dispatch(swal.hideAlert()),
    }
}
```

we now get the alert dialog box poping up (intended behavior) but no text appears in the alert box and the JS console shows the error

> SweetAlert2: Unknown parameter "show"                 (sweetalert2.js:122)

**Question:** What is the correct way to use the `...swal` in `mapDispachToProps` so you do not have to individually select the action creator you like to map dispatch to?

**More Complete Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { swal } from 'react-redux-sweetalert2';
import { getAnimal } from '../../actions';

class Animal extends Component {

    ...    

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        ...
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            getAnimal: (_id) => dispatch(getAnimal(_id)),
            ...swal
        }
    }

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Animal))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can't do like that. You must dispatch an action with an object or a function. For more info look at this [doc](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md).

Correct way would be to use something like:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            getAnimal: (_id) => dispatch(getAnimal(_id)),
            swalAlert: (...swal) => dispatch(swalAlert(...swal)
        }
    }
```

---

To return an object as per the doc, you use like this:

```
const getAnimal = (_id) => dispatch(getAnimal(_id))

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { getAnimal, ...swal })(Animal))
```

Comment: Thanks! Your second method `(mapStateToProps, { getAnimal, ...swal })(Animal)` works! But in your first method, I get `swalAlert is not defined`. How can we get the first approach to work?

Comment: swalAlert need to be defined like you have defined getAnimal. That's just dispatcher method.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { ...myActions, ...swal })(Animal))
```

Be sure to consider the pros and cons of the shorthand version: https://gist.github.com/heygrady/c6c17fc7cbdd978f93a746056f618552#object-short-hand-version